# Trying to edit Wix website HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, velo

How can I edit the HTML, CSS and JS of a Wix site. I cannot seem to find anything that allows you to edit code, it only seems to let you edit through it's awful GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [embed HTML markup](https://www.wix.com/support/html5/old-wix-editor/apps/kb/how-do-i-embed-code-onto-my-wix-site-old-editor) into the site, but [it is not possible to edit the HTML](https://www.wix.com/support/html5/ugc/8c56aa76-1ce2-4596-bc45-d8256a7dc5b2/401d3470-f839-4b69-8270-51f999692f13) of the site itself.

Answer (score 1):

Have you turned on Corvid under 'Dev Mode' on your edit screen? If not, start there. Once Corvid is turned on, you can begin to create and edit your code. For more information, please refer to the [Corvid forum](https://www.wix.com/corvid/forum).

Most times, it takes 1-2 days to get an answer but if you're detailed in your questions, it will give you a better chance.